# How to prevent uploaded image from getting deleted when editing a form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, rest, image-uploading

I'm working on an app that allows users to post events. I'm using NodeJS, Express and Mongo.

I created a form that allows users to input event details, and upload an image relating to the event. I also created a form that allows the user to edit event details.

The form looks as follows:

[image]

**The Problem:**

1. User fills form with event details and attaches a picture.
2. User submits form
3. User decides he wants to change the event title, but NOTHING ELSE
4. User clicks edit event, changes the title, and submits
5. The problem: ***Even though the user didn't delete the picture associated with the event, the picture is no longer there.***

**Here is part of my new.ejs file** (for posting new event, just adding this here for reference)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/eventform.js"></script>
<form action="/events" 
      method="POST" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      onSubmit="return(validate(this));" // validating user input
      novalidate >

    ....
    ....
    <input name="image" type="file" id="image" accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
    <div id="imageBorder" >
        <div id="imageContainer">
            <div id="dropbox">
                 <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                 <p> Drop image here or click to upload</p>
             </div>
             <div id="preview" class="hidden">
             </div>
             <button id="fileSelect" class="...">Upload Image</button>
             <button id="fileRemove" class="...">Remove Image</button>
        </div>
     </div>
     ....
     ....
</form>
```

Notice that I'm using a hidden input field. Also I have two divs, preview (hidden initially) and dropbox. When an image is uploaded, the class 'hidden' is removed from preview and added to dropbox.

**Here is part of the js file newevent.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ....
    eventImageSetup();
    ....
}
....
function eventImageSetup() {
    var dropbox = document.getElementById("dropbox"),
        fileElem = document.getElementById("image"),
        fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
        fileRemove = document.getElementById("fileRemove");
    $(dropbox).height($('#imageBorder').height());
    fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        if (fileElem) {
          fileElem.click();
          e.preventDefault(); // to prevent submit
        }
    }, false);
    fileRemove.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent submit
        if(!$('#preview').hasClass('hidden')) { // if there is an image 
            $('#preview').empty(); 
            $('#dropbox').removeClass('hidden');
            $('#preview').addClass('hidden');
            $('#fileSelect').text('Upload Image');
            $('#image').wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
             $('#image').unwrap();
        }    
        removeError($('#imageError'), $('#image'));
    });
    dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
    dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
    dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
}

function handleFiles(files) { 
   var file = files[0];
   .... // some error checking

   var img = document.createElement("img");
   img.id = "uploadedImage";
   img.file = file;
   img.onload = function() {
          adjustImageSize(img);
   };
   $('#dropbox').addClass('hidden');
   $('#preview').removeClass('hidden');
   $('#preview').empty();
   $('#preview').append(img);
   $('#fileSelect').text('Replace Image');

   var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
                 return function(e) {
                 aImg.src = e.target.result;
          };
    })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

**Here is part of my edit.ejs file**

```
<form action="/events/<%=event._id%>?_method=PUT" 
      method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      onSubmit="return(validate(this));"
      novalidate >

    <input name="image" type="file" id="image" accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">

    <div id="imageBorder" >
        <div id="imageContainer">
              <div id="dropbox" class="hidden">
                    <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <p> Drop image here or click to upload</p>
               </div>
               <div id="preview">
                    <script>
                        var imageExists = '<%=event.image%>';
                        if(imageExists) {
                            var myImg = document.createElement("IMG");
                            var source = "../../<%= event.image %>";
                            myImg.src = source; 
                            adjustImageSize(myImg);
                            $('#preview').append(myImg);
                        }
                        </script>
               </div>
               <button id="fileSelect" class="...">Upload Image</button>
               <button id="fileRemove" class="...">Remove Image</button>
            </div>
     </div> <!-- END OF imageBorder -->
     ....
 </form>
```

The script above succesfully makes the image appear in the edit page, as follows.

[image]

But when you click submit, the picture doesn't show up.

**Here is the nodejs route file. You can see the problem here**

```
// UPDATE SPECIFIC EVENT IN DATABASE 
router.put("/:id", upload.single('image'), middleware.checkEventOwnership, function(req, res) {

    var filepath = undefined;
    if(req.file) {
        filepath = req.file.path.substr(7); // Substr to remove "/public"
    }

    req.body.image = filepath;

    Event.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function(err, foundEvent) {
       if(err) {
           console.log(err);
           req.flash("error", err);
       } else {
           req.flash("success", "Successfully edited your event");
       }
       res.redirect("/events/" + req.params.id);
    });
});
```

Basically, if I leave the image untouched in the edit form, **req.file doesn't exist**. Thus, req.body.image = undefined. And an image is no longer associated with the event.

Common sense would say do this

```
    if(req.file) {
        filepath = req.file.path.substr(7); 
        req.body.image = filepath;
    }
```

But if you do that, you introduce a new problem: If the user edits the event and removes the image (i.e decides he doesn't want an image associated with the event), the image never gets deleted.

**Any idea how to solve this problem?** I know I have to do something in the edit.ejs script... More specifically, I need to create an image file... But I'm not sure how to approach this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this to work through a hack I REALLY don't like. I'm sure there is a better, cleaner, standard way of dealing with edit.ejs and images. In other words, please help me find a better solution!

Here are the changes in edit.ejs

```
<form action="/events/<%=event._id%>?_method=PUT" 
      method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      onSubmit="return validate(this) & editPageImageProcessing(this);"
      novalidate >
     ....
     ....
       <div id="preview">
          <script>
                  var imageExists = '<%=event.image%>';
                  if(imageExists) {
                         var myImg = document.createElement("IMG");
                         var source = "../../<%= event.image %>";
                         myImg.src = source; 
                         myImg.name = "previewImage";
                         myImg.id = "previewImage";
                         adjustImageSize(myImg);
                         $('#preview').append(myImg);
                   }
          </script>
      </div>
```

Basically, I added the lines

```
                         myImg.name = "previewImage";
                         myImg.id = "previewImage";
```

and added a function editPageImageProcessing.

What this function does is: IF the user didn't upload a new image, and did not delete the image, create a hidden input field "hiddenImage", and let its value be the source of the original image. See below:

```
// This function deals with edit image
function editPageImageProcessing(form) {
    // If the user didn't change the image
             // preview would be NOT hidden
             // there would not be a req.file (document.getElementById('image').val == '')
             // we want a hiddenimage input field
    var aFile = document.getElementById('image').value;
    console.log("File: ", aFile);
    var preview = document.getElementById('preview');
    console.log("Preview has hidden class: " + $(preview).hasClass('hidden'));
    if(aFile == '' && !$(preview).hasClass('hidden')) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        $(input).attr("name", "hiddenImage");
        $(input).attr("id", "hiddenImage");
        $(input).attr("type", "hidden");
        var myImage = document.getElementById('previewImage');
        $(input).attr("value", myImage.src);
        $('form').append(input); 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now, in the edit route, I did this

```
// UPDATE SPECIFIC EVENT IN DATABASE 
router.put("/:id", upload.single('image'), middleware.checkEventOwnership, function(req, res) {
    var filepath = undefined;
    if(req.file) { // If user uploaded a new image
        filepath = req.file.path.substr(7); // Substr to remove "/public"
        console.log(filepath);
    } else if(req.body.hiddenImage) { // If user kept the same image
        var index = req.body.hiddenImage.lastIndexOf("/uploads");
        filepath = req.body.hiddenImage.substr(index);
        // req.body.hiddenImage WILL ONLY EXIST if user left image unchanged
    }

    req.body.image = filepath; // If user deleted image, this will be undefined, which is what we want

    Event.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function(err, foundEvent) {
       if(err) {
           console.log(err);
           req.flash("error", err);
       } else {
           req.flash("success", "Successfully edited your event");
       }
       res.redirect("/events/" + req.params.id);
    });
});
```

Okay, so its messy.

Any better solution would be appreciated